# Can there be multiple document environments?

Tags: syntax

Can any conceivable valid input in to a common TeX type of engine have multiple `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` tags? e.g., in another include file, in a if then etc?

Or does TeX only allow that token string to exist once per input? My guess is that it is ok with multiple as it is probably just like any other environment.

Comment: You can have multiple such pairs, but everything after the first `\end{document}` will be ignored.

Comment: LaTeX has `\@onlypreamble\document`, so `\begin{document}` after `\begin{document}` will throw an error.

Comment: The thing is, you are preapring just one document at the time.

Comment: As soon you accidentally would have written `\begin{document}` again after `\begin{document}` and before `\end{document}` you would have noted the error ;-)

Comment: Normally not e.g. but with the standalone *package* you can include documents with preamble and document environment.

Comment: @egreg @Johnnes_B etc You guys are not considering conditionally defined blocks though. e.g., `if X then \begin{document} else { \begin{document} \alpha }` or whatever(psuedo). The conditional will only allow one document but there are multiple "sites". (Not sure if tex allows this or not, which is why I'm asking). Essentially, is it safe to assume to that only one document environment will ever be processed in a process_input_buffer callback in lua except for comments?

Comment: Will the combine package solve your problem? http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "can".

The following document has five `document` environments and runs without error, producing

[image]

But it wouldn't be totally unreasonable for any tool processing "latex documents" to consider this one out of scope.  However any such restriction would need to be specified by that tool, it is not a restriction of latex itself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{
\renewenvironment{document}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
{\renewenvironment{document}{\item}{}
\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
}
\end{document}

\renewenvironment{document}{\bfseries}{}
\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, that means that it can't be unique(one and only one token string per total compilation).

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX has

```
1610 \def\document{\endgroup
1611   \ifx\@unusedoptionlist\@empty\else
1612     \@latex@warning@no@line{Unused global option(s):^^J%
1613             \@spaces[\@unusedoptionlist]}%
...
1659   \ignorespaces}
1660 \@onlypreamble\document
```

which means that `\begin{document}` found inside a `document` environment will throw an error.

Of course nothing would be found after `\end{document}` because of

```
4105 \def\enddocument{%
4106    \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
4107    \@enddocumenthook
4108    \@checkend{document}%
...
4135    \endgroup
4136    \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

so `\@@end` would end the game.

Comment: Yeah, but that is just one case... the case when they are sequentially found.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance If the `\begin{document}` commands are hidden in conditionals and just one of them survives, there are *no* multiple `\begin{document}` commands. Conditional text that's being skipped (because TeX is following the other conditional branch) is never interpreted.

Comment: That may be true but unfortunately doesn't help me because I'm trying to determine that in process_input_buffer, which is blind and multiple cases could be defined on the same line and even in comments. The comments are easy to handle but the general case is not without a full blow parser, which I do not want to write(and why should I, TeX already does it... it just doesn't expose much functionality to do anything serious).